# Algorithm for assigning volunteers to shifts, subject to availability and travel constraints

Tags: algorithm, constraint-programming

Trying to identify a good approach to assigning volunteers to days based several constraints. I feel like this is probably a common enough scenario that there should be a named algorithm for it, but I'm not having much luck finding it yet.

Here is some background info:

- Each volunteer provides a list of shifts they are available (20+)
- Each volunteer must be assigned to a certain number of the shifts (10) from their list
- Each shifts requires a minimum number of volunteers (if there are enough), but that minimum can vary between shifts.
- Most days have one (day) shift, while some are extended by a few hours to form a 2nd (evening) shift.
- Some volunteers live several hours away, while others are more local.
- If there are not enough volunteers to cover all the shifts, we'll leave the schedule blank that shift and manually adjust when additional help is found.
- There are approximately 40 volunteers to cover 100+ shifts. Most will commit to 10 shifts, a couple will commit to 20. A bunch will step up and take extra shifts if coverage is light.

What makes it more complicated is factoring in the scheduling preferences:

- Preference towards assigning volunteers to work adjacent shifts, especially if volunteers are among a particular group.

  - For example, if the volunteer is one who live 3 hours away, try to assign them adjacent days like Friday/Saturday/Sunday rather than several single days to reduce travel time (they'll just stay overnight nearby).
  - Ideally, we would divide the volunteers into 3 groups: **A)** the ones who are local so adjacent shifts don't matter at all *(no/weak preference for adjacent shifts)*, **B)** the ones who live just far enough away that they would prefer adjacent shifts but could manage making separate trips *(medium preference for adjacent shifts)*, and **C)** the ones that live so far away that they'll be staying overnight no matter what. *(strong preference for adjacent shifts)*
- If a day has two shifts, try to fill 2nd shift with volunteers who were also in the 1st shift. If it can't be filled with someone from 1st shift on the same day, try to fill with someone from 1st shift on the next day. (eg, if nobody from Friday Day is available Friday evening, try to find someone from Saturday Day)

EDIT: Added more background information regarding numbers of shifts and what happens if there are not enough volunteers to cover a shift

EDIT 2: added quantity of volunteers and shifts

Comment: It's generally called an "assignment problem". Also sometimes a "marriage" or "bipartite matching" problem in the particular case where the number of volunteers equals the number of shifts and each volunteers wants exactly one shift. Some variants of the problem can be written as integer linear programming, but in your case, the adjacency constraints would necessarily become quadratic constraints, not linear constraints. I'd be tempted to look at https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=integer+programming+quadratic+constraints to see if there has been a similar question.

Comment: Related question asking for solvers: [Solver Recommendation : Discrete Variables and Quadratic Constraints?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6451/solver-recommendation-discrete-variables-and-quadratic-constraints)

Comment: How many volunteers are there approximately?

Comment: @stef There are approximately 40 volunteers to cover 100+ shifts. I added this to the question.

Comment: Just came across the [Nurse Scheduling Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_scheduling_problem), which seems like it might be a good place to start